# Raster reclassification with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, gis

I would like to do with imagemagick a common process in any GIS project, the reclassification of a continuous raster (gtiff format) into several discrete classes. How could I do this task?

I've been reading about using palettes but without success

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).